# react hook form get error object after triggering validation

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

When using `trigger()` on react hook form I can't read the errors object on first attempt.  I think this is because the object populates on a subsequent render.

Here is full working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-firefly-f8ulg7?file=/src/App.tsx

You can see the first time you click submit it logs an empty object and does not set focus.  If you click it again then it will work as intended.

Here is example form code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import classNames from "classnames";

import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    trigger,
    watch,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data: any) => console.log(data);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="form">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <div className={"row"}>
            <div className="label">Name</div>
            <div
              className={classNames({
                input: true,
                error: errors?.name !== undefined
              })}
            >
              <input {...register("name", { required: "Name is required" })} />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="label">Company</div>
            <div
              className={classNames({
                input: true,
                error: errors?.company !== undefined
              })}
            >
              <input
                {...register("company", { required: "Company is required" })}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="label">Tel</div>
            <div
              className={classNames({
                input: true,
                error: errors?.tel !== undefined
              })}
            >
              <input
                {...register("tel", { required: "Telephone is required" })}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="label">Mobile</div>
            <div
              className={classNames({
                input: true,
                error: errors?.mobile !== undefined
              })}
            >
              <input
                {...register("mobile", { required: "Mobile is required" })}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="label">Email</div>
            <div
              className={classNames({
                input: true,
                error: errors?.email !== undefined
              })}
            >
              <input
                {...register("email", { required: "Email is required" })}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div className="button">
        <a
          href="#"
          onClick={() => {
            trigger().then((res) => {
              if (res) {
                
                handleSubmit(onSubmit)();
              } else {
                let elem = errors[Object.keys(errors)[0]]
                  ?.ref as HTMLInputElement;

                elem?.focus();

                // setTimeout(() => {
                //     (errors[Object.keys(errors)[0]]?.ref as HTMLInputElement).focus();
                // }, 10);
                // (errors[Object.keys(errors)[0]]?.ref as HTMLInputElement).focus();

                console.log(errors);
              }
            });
          }}
        >
          Submit
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried using a timeout but it's still empty on the first attempt.

How do I trigger the forms validation and run code based on the results of the validation?

I want to know the errored fields but also have the `ref` that is included inside the error object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the comment from the other answer you can access the error object by using the `getFieldState` in the `useForm` hook and then calling it in your trigger `console.log('error object', getFieldState('name').error)`. You can also just call `console.log('field state', getFieldState('name'))` to get more info for that field, including the error object.

I forked your sandbox with the [updated code](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-cannon-9juj0r).

```js
const {
  register,
  handleSubmit,
  trigger,
  getFieldState,
  watch,
  formState: {
    errors
  }
} = useForm();

<a
href = "#"
onClick = {
    () => {
      trigger().then((res) => {
        if (res) {
          handleSubmit(onSubmit)();
        } else {
          let elem = errors[Object.keys(errors)[0]] ?
            .ref as HTMLInputElement;

          elem ? .focus();

          // setTimeout(() => {
          //     (errors[Object.keys(errors)[0]]?.ref as HTMLInputElement).focus();
          // }, 10);
          // (errors[Object.keys(errors)[0]]?.ref as HTMLInputElement).focus();

          console.log("field state", getFieldState("name"));
          console.log("error object", getFieldState("name").error);
          console.log(errors);
        }
      });
    }
  } >
  Submit
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks you pointed me in right direction.  The answer was a combination of `watch`, `getFieldState` and `setFocus`

Answer (score 0):

**Works for react-hook-form version 7+**

```
import "./styles.css";
import classNames from "classnames";

import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    trigger,
    watch,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
    // send request
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="form">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          // ...
        </form>
      </div>


      // Not under the form
      <button
        className="button"
        onClick={async () => {
          // Check the validation of field
          const validationResult = await trigger('name', {shouldFocus: true});

          // Show the result of validation
          console.log('Field name is valid? ->', validationResult);
          console.log('Field name current value', getValues().name);

          // Submit or not submit the form
          if (validationResult) { handleSubmit(onSubmit)(); }
        }}
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The issue is that I want to submit the form programmatically.  This means I cannot use an embedded submit button inside the form.  The docs say to do this with the handle submit method.  This works fine for submission but I want to have access to be able to trigger validation and then have access to the errors object.

Comment: @Guerrilla look at the new example pls.